# module or component in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to build a shopping cart system in joomla for which I am unable to decide the shopping cart sessions object where should they go and what shall I build a module or a component for that. This cart on checkout should be diverted to paypal and other payment gateways.

Comment: If you can't decide whether to make a module or component then I suggest you should invest more time familiarizing yourself with Joomla's system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try virtuemart, good and easy to use, besides there are a bunch of plugins/modules to support other payment gateways ...